# antlr getting only few symbols

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I have such grammar

```
grammar Hello;

oclFile : ( 'package' packageName
oclExpressions
'endpackage'
)+;
packageName : pathName;
oclExpressions : ( constraint )*;
constraint : contextDeclaration ( Stereotype '@' number name? ':' oclExpression)+;
contextDeclaration : 'context' ( operationContext | classifierContext );
classifierContext : ( name ':' name ) | name;
operationContext : name '::' operationName '(' formalParameterList ')' ( ':' returnType )?;
Stereotype : ( 'pre' | 'post' | 'inv' );
operationName : name | '=' | '+' | '-' | '<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>' | '/' | '*' | '<>' | 'implies' | 'not' | 'or' | 'xor' | 'and';
formalParameterList : ( name ':' typeSpecifier (',' name ':' typeSpecifier )*)?;
typeSpecifier : simpleTypeSpecifier | collectionType;
collectionType : collectionKind '(' simpleTypeSpecifier ')';
oclExpression : ( letExpression )* expression;
returnType : typeSpecifier;
expression : logicalExpression;
letExpression : 'let' name ( '(' formalParameterList ')' )? ( ':' typeSpecifier )? '=' expression ';';
ifExpression : 'if' expression 'then' expression 'else' expression 'endif';
logicalExpression : relationalExpression ( logicalOperator relationalExpression)*;
relationalExpression : additiveExpression (relationalOperator additiveExpression)?;
additiveExpression : multiplicativeExpression ( addOperator multiplicativeExpression)*;
multiplicativeExpression : unaryExpression ( multiplyOperator unaryExpression)*;
unaryExpression : ( unaryOperator postfixExpression) | postfixExpression;
postfixExpression : primaryExpression ( ('.' | '->')propertyCall )*;
primaryExpression : literalCollection | literal | propertyCall | '(' expression ')' | ifExpression;
propertyCallParameters : '(' ( declarator )? ( actualParameterList )? ')';
literal : number | enumLiteral;
enumLiteral : name '::' name ( '::' name )*;
simpleTypeSpecifier : pathName;
literalCollection : collectionKind '{' ( collectionItem (',' collectionItem )*)? '}';
collectionItem : expression ('..' expression )?;
propertyCall : pathName ('@' number)? ( timeExpression )? ( qualifiers )? ( propertyCallParameters )?;
qualifiers : '[' actualParameterList ']';
declarator : name ( ',' name )* ( ':' simpleTypeSpecifier )? ( ';' name ':' typeSpecifier '=' expression )? '|';
pathName : name ( '::' name )*;
timeExpression : '@' 'pre';
actualParameterList : expression (',' expression)*;
logicalOperator : 'and' | 'or' | 'xor' | 'implies';
collectionKind : 'Set' | 'Bag' | 'Sequence' | 'Collection';
relationalOperator : '=' | '>' | '<' | '>=' | '<=' | '<>';
addOperator : '+' | '-';
multiplyOperator : '*' | '/';
unaryOperator : '-' | 'not';
LOWERCASE  : 'a'..'z' ;
UPPERCASE  : 'A'..'Z' ;
DIGITS  : '0'..'9' ;
name : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | '_') ( LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGITS | '_' )* ;
number : DIGITS (DIGITS)* ( '.' DIGITS (DIGITS)* )?;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

and such expression

```
package RobotsTestModel
context motor 
inv@0:
self.power = 100
endpackage
```

but I'm getting only "mot" in variable text:

```
 public override bool VisitConstraint([NotNull] HelloParser.ConstraintContext context)
    {
      VisitContextDeclaration(context.contextDeclaration());
      string text = context.contextDeclaration().classifierContext().GetText();
```

It's also strange that sometimes it's retrieve motoo if I change, but without certainty. It writes like it expects Stereotype instead of "or" -- the last part of "motor". Where should I work to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar produces tokens `m`, `o`, `t`, `or` tokens from input `motor`, because `name` is not a lexer rule and does not work in token recognition. And only `m`, `o`, `t` tokens are matched by rule `name`, it does not expect `or` token, that's why you see this strange results.

You should make lexer rules for names and numbers instead of parser ones:

```
NAME   : [a-zA-Z_]+ [a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ;
```

So `motor` will be a single token.